# Add Tooltip to Tab component Material UI

Tags: material-ui

How do you add a tooltip to Material-UI Tab component?

I can easily add the Toolip to the `Tabs` component by wrapping the Tabs component like this
`<Tooltip><Tabs /></Tooltip>` but performing the same action on a Tab component renders it unable to switch. This sandbox illustrates the problem, you can switch between second and third tabs but not to the first Tab.

The demo is here https://codesandbox.io/s/20p06mnxq0

Comment: I have been answered in the issue https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12597#issuecomment-414437325